# How can I move files between folders in the Dropbox app?

Tags: dropbox

I am using the Dropbox app on a Samsung tablet (Android 4.1.1) and I need to move files from the current folder into a new folder that I have created in the current folder.

I can create a new folder with the menu in the top right but I cannot see how to move files into the folder.  The pull-down menu associated with each file only contains options for `Share Favorite Delete Rename Export`.

NOTE: I have a terminal on my tablet and I am not opposed to using that but going to `com.dropbox.android` does not show the updated version of shared folders from Dropbox (but this is a whole other question I need to ask!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu for each file (the one you get by clicking the down-triangle-in-ring icon, or by long-tapping a file) should also have a **Move** item between **Rename** and **Export**. Clicking it brings up a selector you can use to select where to move it to. I can't imagine why you might not have that item.

Comment: That is what I would have expected as well... but it is not there on any of my files.

Comment: It seems it was just a glitch or an odd setting I inadvertently set...  I deleted all of the folders and made them anew and the `move` option has returned.